# Select max values from a column grouped by a different column from 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a complicated problem, and I am not very good with MYSQL. I hope somebody can help me out.
I have 2 tables. A snippet of these tables:

1. Members_per_year

ID | Member_ID | Business_year_ID | AS_ID
1...........1............................56...................12
10004...1............................55...................12
10005...1............................54...................11
10002...1............................57...................30
2...........2............................58...................40
3...........3............................58...................27

2. Year

ID | Business_year
54......2012-2013
55......2013-2014
56......2014-2015
57......2015-2016
58......2016-2017

What I am trying to do is to combine the two tables on the Members_per_year. Business_year_ID and the Year.ID columns. After which, I want to group the data by Member_ID, so I get back 1 row per member. The catch is that it should be the data with the largest Business_year for that member. I managed to put together a query, but it’s not working correctly. The Query is:

```
SELECT Member_ID, Business_year_ID, MAX(Year.Business_year), Year.ID AS YearID, AS_ID  
FROM Members_per_year  
INNER JOIN Year ON Members_per_year.Business_year_ID = Year.ID  
GROUP BY Member_ID
```

And it returns:

Member_ID | Business_year_ID | MAX(Year.Business_year) | YearID | AS_ID
1...........................56...............................2015-2016....................56..........12
2...........................58...............................2016-2017....................58..........40
3...........................58...............................2016-2017....................58..........27

It returns the correct max Business_year, but the associated Business_year_ID and YearID is not correct. Basically it selects the first value for the Business_year_ID  and the MAX for the Business_year. Not the Business_year_ID corresponding to the MAX(Business_year). Does anybody has any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

**Edit:**
I am deliberately searching for the Business_year and not for the Business_year_ID. This is a precautionary matter, in case the higher ID is not equal with an actual higher Business year.

Comment: The values returned for the non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list are indeterminate if those expressions aren't included in the `GROUP BY` clause. We can get MySQL to throw an error (similar to the behavior of other RDBMS) if we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the sql_mode.  The value returned for `YearID` column is from *some* row in the group. It's not necessarily from the row with the maximum value of `BusinessYear`.) The behavior documented here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, I thought that something similar was happening. It is a bit annoying that it is picking just the max value, and not the row corresponding to the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to get the max year per member, then join the result with the original tables:

```
select b.*, c.*
from (
  select Member_ID, max(Business_year_ID) y
  from Members_per_year
  group by Member_ID) a
join Members_per_year b on a.Member_ID = b.Member_ID and a.y = b.Business_year_ID
join Year c on b.Business_year_ID = c.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your proposition in PHPMyadmin, but it said the query is not correct. I think it has problem with having a bracket after the from clause. The error is: "An expression was expected. (near ( )". And there are a couple more but probably related to the same error. (It has problem with the second SELECT, closing bracket and with "a").

Comment: And I see that you searched for MAX(Business_year_ID) while I need the max of Year.Business_year for the same member, So I need to search for a MAX of the joint table.